# Jenkins Groovy script works in Windows but not Linux

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

The below code is working fine in Windows (groovy script shell of jenkins) but when i execute it on groovy script shell of jenkins in Linux its throwing the error:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.withReader() is applicable for argument types:
>   (Script1$_run_closure1) values: [Script1$_run_closure1@71c12adb]  at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>     at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:8)    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.GroovyScript.call(GroovyScript.java:122)
>     at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:45)  at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.ScriptHelper.runScript(ScriptHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.util.ScriptHelper.runScript(ScriptHelper.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptler.ScriptlerManagement.doTriggerScript(ScriptlerManagement.java:470)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)

Here's the code; I pass the value for `Select_Folders`:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import java.nio.file.Paths

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def folder_struct 

Paths.get('C:\\Json_Results\\results.json').withReader { reader ->
    folder_struct = slurper.parse(reader)
}

return folder_struct [Select_Folders]
```

Could anyone please help me with the problem? Of course, I have changed the path `C:\\Json_Results\\results.json` to `/home/project/results.json` when running on Linux.

Comment: My first question would be "what version of Groovy are you running in Jenkins?"  Path extensions have only been in Groovy since v 2.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Path extensions were only added to Groovy in v2.3.0

I suspect you have an old version of Groovy on your Jenkins nodes.

You should just be able to use a File instead:

```
def folder_struct = new File('C:\\Json_Results\\results.json').withReader { reader ->
    slurper.parse(reader)
}
```

Comment: excellent it worked yeah on linux node groovy is older version ;)